# Inverse of Hölder's inequality

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I was taught the following statement without proof.

\begin{align}
  &\left\|fg\right\|_{L^2} \leq C\left\|g\right\|_{L^2}, \ 
  \forall g\in L^2 \\
  &\Rightarrow f\in L^{\infty}  
\end{align}

Do you know any reference that explains this?
Or, do you have any ideas how to prove?

Answer (score 0):

It is not true for non-$\sigma$-finite spaces. So, I'll presume $(X,\mu,\mathcal{A})$ is a $\sigma$-finite space.

We will show $\|f\|_\infty \le C$ by contradiction. Assume to the contrary, so that
$$
\{|f|>C\}
$$ has a positive measure. This set may have infinite measure. Let $(E_n)_{n\ge 1}\subset\mathcal A$ be disjoint family such that $\cup_{n\ge 1}E_n = X$. Since $$
\bigcup_{n\ge 1}\left(E_n \cap \{|f|>C\}\right)
$$ has a posive measure, there exists $n_0$ such that $E_{n_0}\cap \{|f|>C\} =: F$ has a positive measure. Let $g=1_F\in L^2$, then the assumption implies that
$$
\int_X |fg|^2 = \int_F |f|^2\le C^2\|g\|_{L^2}^2 = C^2\mu (F).
$$ From this, we know
$$
\int_F \left(|f|^2-C^2\right)\le 0
$$ while $|f|^2-C^2>0$ on $F$. Since $\mu(F)>0$ by construction, this leads to the contradiction. From this, we conclude that $\{|f|> C\}$ has a null $\mu$-measure, establishing $\|f\|_{L^\infty}\le C$.